# How to access previous state in ui-router $transitions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is my .run function:

```
.run(function ($transitions, UserService) {
    $transitions.onStart({ to: function(state) {
        return state.data != null && state.data.requireLogin === true && UserService.getUser().isLogged !== true;
    }},function(trans){
        var AuthService = trans.injector().get('AuthService');
        var $q = trans.injector().get('$q');
        var $state = trans.injector().get('$state');
        var defer = $q.defer();
        AuthService.login().then(function (status){
            if(status === 'login'){
                defer.resolve(true);
            }else if (status === 'register'){
                defer.resolve($state.target('map.register'));
            }
        }, function (msg){
            //  Here is part that I am asking for
            defer.resolve(false);
        });

        return defer.promise;   
    });
});
```

Basically if transiting to state that requires login and user is not logged in `transitionHookFn` is used. There I use `AuthService.login()` and return promise of status. if `AuthService.login()` fails (users cancels) promise will return false and cancel the transition thus leaving user in same state where he was.

Problem starts when user tries to access restricted page on first load and cancels the login because there is no previous state and whole page is just blank.

Is there a way to cancel transition if there is previous state, if not then redirect to home? I would need to access previous state and see if it there.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to home page you can use

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('YOUR-HOME-STATE');
});
```

You can also use

```
app.run(function($transitions, SOME-SERVICE) {
    $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'SOME-STATE' }, function(trans) {
        //Here you can call your service and based on conditions 
        //you can make transition to previous state by calling its name
        //or to your default state
        if(SOME-CONDITION){
            return trans.router.stateService.go('PREVIOUS-STATE');
        } else {
            return trans.router.stateService.go('DEFAULT-STATE');
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you can also use `stateParams` better used as `$transition$` params here using:

```
trans.params().PARAM-NAME
```